# Setting up jacoco for multi-module Android codebase with Gadle kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, jacoco, android-jacoco

I am currently setting up Jacoco in an Android codebase that my team built. I don't have much experience in Android but I have set up Jacoco before in a Spring Boot codebase so that I can track the test coverage in Sonarqube. But I am having hard time doing in the Android codebase.

So the directory layout looks like this

```
MyApp/
├─ app/
│  ├─ build/
│  ├─ src/
│  ├─ build.gradle.kts
├─ buildSrc/
│  ├─ build.gradle.kts
├─ modules/
│  ├─ module1/
│  │  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ build.gradle.kts
│  ├─ module2/
│  │  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ build.gradle.kts
├─ build.gradle.kts
├─ gradle.properties
├─ gradlew
├─ settings.gradle.kts
```

I tried adding `jacoco` in the `MyApp/build.gradle.kts`.

```
plugins {
    id(Dependencies.Plugins.androidApplication) version Dependencies.Versions.androidAppplication apply false
    id(Dependencies.Plugins.androidLibrary) version Dependencies.Versions.androidLibrary apply false
    id(Dependencies.Plugins.hilt) version Dependencies.Versions.hilt apply false
    id(Dependencies.Plugins.openApi) version Dependencies.Versions.openApi
    id(Dependencies.Plugins.kotlinAndroid) version Dependencies.Versions.kotlinAndroid apply false
    id(Dependencies.Plugins.sonarqube) version Dependencies.Versions.sonarqube
    
    id("jacoco")
}
```

I tried executing `bash gradlew test jacocoTestReport` but it says

```
Task 'jacocoTestReport' not found in root project 'MyApp' and its subprojects.
```

I tried adding the line below in the `MyApp/build.gradle.kts`, per JaCoco Plugin documentation (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html)

```
tasks.test {
    finalizedBy(tasks.jacocoTestReport) // report is always generated after tests run
}
tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn(tasks.test) // tests are required to run before generating the report
}
```

but the output says something like below

```
Script compilation errors:

  Line 12: tasks.test {
                 ^ Unresolved reference: test

  Line 13:     finalizedBy(tasks.jacocoTestReport)                                              
               ^ Unresolved reference: finalizedBy
```

I did similar configuration in a Spring Boot project before which ran normal. But here it cannot even detect task `jacocoTestReport`.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a traditional Java or Kotlin JVM project, there is a single test task, accessible via `tasks.test`.

However, in an Android project, there isn't a single `test` task. Instead, there are multiple test tasks, [one for each build variant](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/advanced-test-setup). The test tasks are named `test<Variant>UnitTest`. For example, you might have `testDebugUnitTest` and `testReleaseUnitTest`.

When you try to access `tasks.test` in an Android project, it results in an "Unresolved reference: test" error because there is no task with the name `test`.

Similarly, `finalizedBy(tasks.jacocoTestReport)` is a way to specify task dependencies, saying that the `jacocoTestReport` task should always be run after the `test` task. However, since there is no `test` task in an Android project, this results in an "`Unresolved reference: finalizedBy`" error.

---

Following "[How do I add plugins to subprojects based on what plugins are present?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35352859/6309)", you might need to create a Jacoco setup in your root `build.gradle.kts` that automatically applies the correct Jacoco setup for each module that uses the Android plugin.

Using a [Gradle DLS script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:scripts):

```kotlin
import org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport

plugins {
    // your existing plugins...

    id("jacoco")
}

// rest of your configurations...

subprojects { subproject ->
    subproject.plugins.withId(Dependencies.Plugins.androidApplication) {
        setupJacoco(subproject)
    }
    subproject.plugins.withId(Dependencies.Plugins.androidLibrary) {
        setupJacoco(subproject)
    }
}


fun setupJacoco(project: Project) {
    project.tasks.register("jacocoTestReport", JacocoReport::class.java) { task ->
        task.group = "Reporting"
        task.description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
        task.reports {
            xml.isEnabled = true
            html.isEnabled = true
        }
        task.executionData.setFrom(
            project.fileTree(project.buildDir).apply {
                include("**/jacoco/*.exec")
            }
        )
        task.sourceDirectories.setFrom(
            project.files(
                project.extensions.getByType<SourceSetContainer>().getByName("main").allSource.srcDirs
            )
        )
        task.classDirectories.setFrom(
            project.fileTree(
                project.extensions.getByType<SourceSetContainer>().getByName("main").output.classesDirs
            )
        )
    }
}
```

That script will check every subproject in the build. If a subproject applies your IDs, like `Dependencies.Plugins.androidApplication` or `Dependencies.Plugins.androidLibrary` plugin, it adds Jacoco tasks for that subproject.
For each of these projects, add a `jacocoTestReport` task which generates the Jacoco reports.

One important thing to note is that the Android Gradle plugin [creates a `test` task for each build variant](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_tasks) of the app/library module. For example, if you have `debug` and `release` build types, the Android Gradle plugin will create `testDebugUnitTest` and `testReleaseUnitTest` tasks.

Meaning, you will need to run the specific `test` task and then `jacocoTestReport` like this:

```bash
# Do this once, after making changes to your build.gradle.kts 
./gradlew --refresh-dependencies

# Then, each time you want to generate the report
./gradlew module1:testDebugUnitTest module1:jacocoTestReport
```

That will run the unit tests for `module1` and then generate the Jacoco report. Note that if you are using product flavors, you might have more than two types of `test` tasks (e.g., `testFreeDebugUnitTest`, `testPaidDebugUnitTest`, etc.), so do adjust your command accordingly to fit your project configuration.

---

> How to consolidate results into single report?

Consolidating JaCoCo coverage reports from multiple modules into a single report in a multi-module Android project means aggregating the execution data (`*.exec` files) and source information from all relevant subprojects.

That would require a custom Gradle task in your root `build.gradle.kts` file that gathers data from all modules and generates a comprehensive report.

In your root `build.gradle.kts`, define a task that will collect and aggregate coverage data from all subprojects. That task will depend on all individual `jacocoTestReport` tasks to make sure all coverage data is available before aggregation.

```kotlin
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test
import org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport

// Define a task that aggregates all Jacoco reports into one
tasks.register("jacocoRootReport", JacocoReport::class.java) { rootReportTask ->
    rootReportTask.group = "Verification"
    rootReportTask.description = "Generates an aggregated report from all subprojects."
    
    // Paths to include in the report
    val sourcePaths = files(subprojects.map { it.projectDir.resolve("src/main/kotlin") })
    val classPaths = files(subprojects.map { it.buildDir.resolve("intermediates/javac/debug/classes") })
    val executionDataPaths = files(subprojects.map { it.buildDir.resolve("jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec") })

    // Set the class directories, source directories, and execution data
    rootReportTask.classDirectories.setFrom(classPaths.filter { it.exists() })
    rootReportTask.sourceDirectories.setFrom(sourcePaths.filter { it.exists() })
    rootReportTask.executionData.setFrom(executionDataPaths.filter { it.exists() })

    // Specify report formats (e.g., HTML, XML)
    rootReportTask.reports {
        xml.required.set(true)
        html.required.set(true)
    }

    // Make sure this task runs after all individual jacocoTestReport tasks
    subprojects.forEach { subproject ->
        subproject.tasks.withType(JacocoReport::class.java).configureEach { task ->
            rootReportTask.dependsOn(task)
        }
    }
}
```

The example paths provided (`src/main/kotlin`, `intermediates/javac/debug/classes`, `jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec`) are based on a typical Android project structure: adapt them based on your project's configuration:

- Use `src/main/java` if your project primarily uses Java.
- Adjust the class paths if your build variants differ (e.g., replace `debug` with `release` if you are generating reports for release builds).
- If your modules use different paths for source or class files, make sure these are correctly reflected.

To generate the aggregated report, run the following command:

```bash
./gradlew clean jacocoRootReport
```

That would first cleans previous builds to make sure fresh data is used for the report, then runs the `jacocoRootReport` task, which aggregates data from all subprojects.